# What's the longest word that has survived from Old English?

Tags: orthography, history, old-english, syllables

I recently saw this question [Did the "We shall fight on the beaches" speech mainly use words from Old English? If so, why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97665/did-the-we-shall-fight-on-the-beaches-speech-mainly-use-words-from-old-english) about Winston Churchill's famous "Fight them on the beaches" speech that said the speech mostly used words from Old English because they are simpler than most of the ones borrowed from French and Latin.

I'd really like to ask what the most complicated word is from Old English but that's far too subjective. What is the longest word still in use in today's English that comes from Old English? I will accept an answer either in terms of spelling or number of syllables. Proper nouns are not included.  The word also should be of Germanic origin rather than being an Old English borrowing from Latin or French.

Comment: Does it need to have been one word in Old English as well?

Comment: @sumelic how do you define "word" for this purpose?

Comment: @phoog: I'd think CJ Dennis's definitions are more relevant. But I'd just define it by spacing, which was generally used in Old English texts.

Comment: @sumelic I guess both compound and non-compound words would be interesting. Preferably the word should be as close as possible to Old English. In this case I would consider something like _zig zag_ as a single word despite the space.

Comment: I suspect that @sumelic had in mind such words as *housewife* and *husband.* One is still recognisable in modern English as a compound; the other is not.  What do you think about that?

Comment: @phoog Let's try to keep the question as objective as possible while not narrowing it too much. So both would be acceptable. I realise that a lot of change has happened (which is why they're different languages!) The answer might need to be a short list of words in a few (not too many!) categories.

Comment: @sumelic No. I want words that have a meaning. I live in Australia, so a place name from England mightn't mean anything to me, whereas a word (adjective, verb, etc.) from Old English _could_ mean the same thing to all Modern English speakers.

Comment: @sumelic I'd prefer not. I want the most "Germanic" words.

Comment: To be accurate, Churchill's words where OE in origin rather than OE survivors in themselves, the only exception being "surrender" which is French in origin. I am convinced that this was a deliberate dig at the French. My offering, assuming that neologisms or later compound words like 'broadsword' are not allowed: foreboding

Answer (score 4):

Longest words I've found so far:

- *thousandfold* (12 letters, three syllables); the Oxford English dictionary says it is from Old English *þúsendfeald*
- *drunkenness* (11 letters, three syllables): Old English *druncenness*; there also are attested cases of [*oferdruncenness*](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/024038) which would be even better if it were a modern English word
- *overshadow* (10 letters, four syllables): Old English [*ofersceadwian*](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/024209)

With the suffix *-ly* (not sure if these count as they are transparently composed of modern English adjectives plus a modern English suffix, so there's no way to prove continuity of transmission as a whole from Old English):

- *shamelessly* (11 letters, 3 syllables) pretty much seems to mean the same thing as [*sceamleáslíce*](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/026555) according to Bosworth-Teller
- *soothsayingly* (13 letters, 4 syllables): not commonly used in Modern English, also has changed meaning; Old English [*sóþsecgendlíce*](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/058321) just meant "truly" according to Bosworth-Teller
- *unweatherly* (11 letters, 4 syllables): The Oxford English Dictionary has a citation from 1889, "R. L. Stevenson *Master of Ballantrae* ix,   About the top of it ran considerable bulwarks, which made the ship unweatherly." Old English [*unwederlíce*](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/033954) means "in a way that indicates bad weather, threateningly" according to Bosworth-Teller

Comment: _oferdruncenness_=_overdrunkenness_? [Google books: Squeeze This!](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=bPhXe_qNy5QC&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22overdrunkenness%22&source=bl&ots=LF8F6qthJv&sig=P9sd3bAxeg_lpjkg74RD6Sum7SM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifgsPA1-rKAhVKH5QKHcgYCWkQ6AEIGTAB#v=onepage&q=%22overdrunkenness%22&f=false), [Google books: Gates of Empire](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=uox-CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=%22overdrunkenness%22&source=bl&ots=TqdhnZUF7P&sig=2hBpYv47v_5iJDmnsizJPEqyiD0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifgsPA1-rKAhVKH5QKHcgYCWkQ6AEIHDAC#v=onepage&q=%22overdrunkenness%22&f=false).