# What is the difference between Desire and Will?

Tags: meaning, differences

I have the following exercise in my schoolbook:

[image]

As you can see, I had to match the phrases with the respective gaps.

My question is:
**Why can I not swap will and desire?**

Here is my research (I used the **Cambridge Dictionary**):

> **Will** -  1) what someone wants to happen 2) the mental power used to
>   control and direct your thoughts and actions, or a determination to do
>   something, despite any difficulties or opposition
>
> **Desire** -  a strong feeling that you want something

Having done this research, I don't see the difference between these two words and in which context each would be more appropriate.

Comment: Imagine there's a pretty girl over there.  You have the desire to go talk to her, but not the will.

Answer (score 2):

There are many definitions for each, but generally the following I think is a half-decent explanation, even if a little simplistic.

Desire is something you want.

Will is something you have.

Desire means wanting a flashy car, or a juicy steak.

Will is the strength and condition you have to start something and follow it through, to take action. It's fitting that another word "willpower" has "will" in it, because in a way it's the strength in you to carry out your actions.

Will is your resolve.
resolve
15. something determined or decided; resolution: he had made a resolve to work all day.
16. firmness of purpose; determination: nothing can break his resolve. 
[Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resolve)

So in your example sentences, (I know I'm simplifying) imagine:

"I always feel a desire/willpower to run away." 
"I guess I just don't have the desire/willpower to win."

willpower
The strength of will to carry out one's decisions, wishes, or plans.
[Willpower](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/willpower)

HotLicks' comment under your question probably sums it up best.

Answer (score 0):

[Will](https://www.etymonline.com/word/will)

> Old English will, willa "mind, determination, purpose; desire, wish, request (*Etymonline*)

[Desire](https://www.etymonline.com/word/desire)

> (n.) c. 1300, from Old French desir, from desirer; sense of "lust" is first recorded mid-14c.  (v) early 13c., from Old French desirrer (12c.) "wish, desire, long for," from Latin desiderare "long for, wish for; demand, expect," original sense perhaps "await what the stars will bring," from the phrase de sidere "from the stars," from sidus (genitive sideris) "heavenly body, star, constellation" (*Etymonline*)

There is a certain overlap with **desire** and **will** as to meaning.
In practical use **will** means more determination than wish, and **desire** more wish than determination.

**Desire** might mean a passing fancy, but **will** might mean a long term fancy. **Will** might mean a set path, while **desire** would more often mean a short detour.

Often the older words in English take on a power the more recent acquisitions lack. So, words with similar meanings have different uses. [See](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97665/did-the-we-shall-fight-on-the-beaches-speech-mainly-use-words-from-old-english)  this previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Will, generally, is the faculty of the mind that selects, at the moment of decision, a desire among the various desires present; it itself does not refer to any particular desire, but rather to the mechanism responsible for choosing from among one's desires.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_(philosophy)

Comment: How the distinction between the two works in a philosophical context is very much theory-dependent; it is impossible to give useful definitions of these terms that would work across all philosophical theories that use them.